# Guaranteed the final order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, async-await

I am starting to use async and await.
My problem is the following, I am making an api call X number of times, I need the final result to stay in the order that I am looping through that array but I am not sure if I am doing it right because of my console.log It's not being displayed like I think it should

The Data

```
 Data = [  
           { paymentId: '784', pnr: 'Z8PQ3T', email: 'test@gmail.com' },
           { paymentId: '211', pnr: 'Z8PQ3T', email: 'test@gmail.com' },
           { paymentId: '325', pnr: 'L4MEQC', email: 'test@gmail.com' },
           { paymentId: '454', pnr: 'A357HS', email: 'abc@d.com' },
           { paymentId: '674', pnr: 'QCYCGX', email: 'abc@d.com' },
           { paymentId: '723', pnr: 'W41BTV', email: 'test@gmail.com' },
           { paymentId: '812', pnr: 'HE4JUR', email: 'test@gmail.com' },
          ]
```

Mi function

```
  const getPayments = async payments => {
    return Promise.all(payments.map(async (payment, i) => {
      let { pnr, email, paymentId } = payment
      let pay = JSON.parse(await getDataNavitaire(pnr, email))
      console.log(`Pay numero ${i}`, pay);
      pay = validationPaymentsNUEVO(pay, paymentId)
      if (pay) {
        pay.paymentIdEntrante = paymentId
        pay.isReprocessPayment = isReprocess
      }
      return pay
    }))
```

Result of console log is 2, 0, 1, 4, 3
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyYJK.png)

So, how can i assure the output of the console log are in order? (0,1,2...N), what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The resulting array returned by `getPayments` is already in the desired order, because you're using `Promise.all` with `.map` properly: the `n`th element of the input array will correspond to the `n`th element of the resolve array.

Since you aren't controlling *when* each separate `console.log` runs, it appears that they run in a random order (depending on when the result is received) - but the returned `pay` at the end of the `.map` callback will still be in the correct order.

If you wanted to make the Promises run in serial so that `0`, then `1`, etc gets logged, do:

```
const getPayments = async payments => {
  const pays = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < payments.length; i++) {
      const { pnr, email, paymentId } = payments[i];
      let pay = JSON.parse(await getDataNavitaire(pnr, email))
      console.log(`Pay numero ${i}`, pay);
      // ...
      pays.push(pay);
  }
  return pays;
};
```

But your current `Promise.all` version is faster and more appropriate. I'd use it, and log the array *after* the `getPayments` is done, eg:

```
const result = await getPayments(payments);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for taking the time to help me. Finally i make some edits on my code and get something like this... What do you think? [NewCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXfdd.jpg) So...all the promises are done right? so after that for having console.log according to each payment i did another map with the results and calling the id of the first entering Array ps: I forgot do un-comment the console.log line (below the json parse payment)

Comment: If `getDataNavitaire` returns a Promise, that looks reasonable.

Comment: no :( just return a really big big json object, each payment of the promiseAll is a call to an api that returns a json of about 1500-3000 lines

Comment: If it doesn't return a Promise, then it doesn't make sense to call `Promise.all` on an array of them. Only use `Promise.all` on arrays of Promises

Comment: mm but if i need to wait to all the api calls are finished before the code continues why is make no sense use a promise? i mean, i understand promiseAll wait until all the execution inside finish before moves on